# How to create a popup with any number of buttons?

Tags: python, pyqt5, popup

In PyQt5, I'm attempting to create a class that implements a popup with an arbitrary number of buttons.  I think that I'm close, but when I display the thing, neither the message nor the buttons are visible.  I will be grateful for any suggestions.  It seems as though no one else has tried to do something like this, which is a bit surprising.  Stackoverflow wants a longer description of the problem, but I really don't have anything else to say.

```
import os, sys, time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QTextEdit, \
  QToolButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Popup(QDialog):
   """
   Overview
   --------

   This class implements a substitute for the QMessageBox widget.  `Popup` allows the user to
   define an arbitrary number of buttons with arbitrary names.  The widget can be either modal
   or non-modal.


   Note
   ----

   `Popup` inherits from `QDialog` rather than `QWidget`; otherwise, it would not function as a
   popup widget.
   """


   # Section 11.1: Constructor.

   def __init__(self, *, text="Your message goes here.", button_names=None, icon='warning',
     width=900, height=300, button_style_sheets=None, button_widths=None, parent=None,
     title='', modal=True):
      """
      Inputs
      ------

      `text` is a string containing the text to be displayed.  One can use HTML to control
      fonts, colors, etc.  If one does not specify the font, one gets the default font, which is
      very small.

      `title` is the window title, which is by default an empty string.

      `button_names`, which is `None`, a single string, or a list of strings, optionally names
      the buttons to be displayed below the text.  If there are multiple buttons, these are
      displayed from left to right in the order specified.

      If `button_names` is `None`, the `icon` string determines which buttons are displayed:
      'critical' causes a single 'OK' button to be displayed; anything else causes a pair of
      buttons, with labels 'Yes' and 'No', to be displayed.

      `icon` is the name of the icon to be displayed.  The default is 'warning', which causes
      the code to load the file `warning.ico`.

      `width` and `height` are the width and height of the window in units of pixels.
      """

      super().__init__(parent=parent)

      self.setModal(modal)

      self.setWindowTitle(title)

      self.grid= QGridLayout()
      self.setLayout(self.grid)

      self.textedit= QTextEdit(text)
      self.textedit.setFixedWidth (width)
      self.textedit.setFixedHeight(height)
      self.textedit.setStyleSheet('font-size: 14pt;')

      if button_names is None:

         # Assign default button names:
         if icon.startswith('warning') or icon.startswith('stop'):
            button_names= ['OK']
         else:
            button_names= ['Yes', 'No']

      elif isinstance(button_names, str):
         button_names= [button_names]

      if button_style_sheets is None:
         button_style_sheets= []

         for button_name in button_names:
            if   button_name.lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
               button_style_sheets.append('font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold; color: #00AA00')
            elif button_name.lower() in ('n', 'no'):
               button_style_sheets.append('font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold; color: #FF0000')
            else:
               button_style_sheets.append('font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold')

      if isinstance(button_widths, int):

         # All button widths are the same:
         button_widths= len(button_names) * [button_widths]

      elif button_widths is None:
         button_widths= []

         for button_name in button_names:

            # Set button widths based on the number of characters in the name.
            # The resulting widths are not perfect.
            button_widths.append(20 * (len(button_name) + 2))


      if icon:

         # There is an icon.  ==> The icon occupies the first position in both rows and
         # everything else is pushed one position to the right.

         if icon.endswith('.png'):
            from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
            qim= ImageQt(icon)
            pix= QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
            label= QLabel()
            label.setPixmap(pix)
            self.grid.addWidget(label     , 0, 0, 1, 1)
         else:
            self.icon= QToolButton()
            self.icon.setIcon(QIcon(icon))
            self.grid.addWidget(self.icon , 0, 0, 1, 1)

         self.grid.addWidget(self.textedit, 0, 1, 1, len(button_names)+1)

      else:
         self.grid.addWidget(self.textedit, 0, 0, 1, len(button_names)+1)

      self.buttons= []

      for i, button_name in enumerate(button_names):
         button= QPushButton(button_name, parent=self)
         button.setFixedWidth(button_widths[i])

         if isinstance(button_style_sheets, str):
            button.setStyleSheet(button_style_sheets)
         else:
            button.setStyleSheet(button_style_sheets[i])

         self.buttons.append(button)

         self.grid.addWidget(button, 1, i+bool(icon), 1, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)

         def make_func(button_name):
            def set_result():
               self.result= button_name
            return set_result

         def close():
            self.close()

         button.clicked.connect(make_func(button_name))
         button.clicked.connect(close)

      # end for i, button_name in button_names

   # end def __init__


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
popup= Popup(text="Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.",
  button_names=['Yes', 'No', 'Maybe'])
popup.show()
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: What's the point of `time.sleep()`?!? No blocking function should **ever** be used in the main app thread. Remove that, and add `app.exec_()` at the end, or change `popup.show()` to `popup.exec_()`.

Comment: There are other issues, btw. While you can obviously do whatever you want with your subclasses, you should better use and implement existing features, most importantly the reply from `exec_` (which is what the existing [`result`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#result) already does, by the way), and also ensuring that it properly behaves on `accept`/`reject` or their signals, meaning that you shouldn't just use `close`. Also, there's no need for PIL, as QPixmap is capable of loading png images. Finally, you should really avoid unconventional spacings: they really provide no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use time.sleep() in Qt, if you want the program to show for a certain time then use a QTimer that invokes the quit() method.

```py
QTimer.singleShot(3 * 1000, QCoreApplication.quit)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you just want to close the popup window and not all the other windows then connect it to the close() method:

```py
QTimer.singleShot(3 * 1000, popup.close)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```